# Angularjs ngRoute not working from jsp to html- Still issue persists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I am using ngRoute for simple redirection . I have an index.jsp file which has only the ngView tag. I have script.js where my ngRoute is define. All I need is when I hit index.jsp it should load the home.html file in ngView. But this is not happening.  Am not seeing any error in console.

**Index.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>QuoteDetails</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/index.jsp', {
            templateUrl : '/home.html',
            controller  : 'MyController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
        redirect: '/home.html'
    });

});



app.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
         $scope.test="hellos";
         console.log($scope.test);
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'UserController'
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.user= data;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                });

        };
}]);
```

**home.html**

```
 <div ng-init="getDataFromServer()">
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example" style="border-collapse: collapse, width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quote No</th>
                <th>Quote Amt</th>
                <th>Quote Contact</th>
                <th colspan=2>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <!--  <c:forEach  var="user" items="${users}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.quoteNo}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.quoteAmt}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.quoteContact}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach> -->
      <tr ng-repeat="item in user track by $index">
               <td>{{item.quoteNo}}</td>
               <td>{{item.quoteAmt}}</td>
               <td>{{item.quoteContact}}</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you should use `ng-view=" "` outside the `<body>` tag, and you have not included `scipt.js` in index page

Answer (score 0):

Add path of **script.js** in index page and add module name in **app.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>QuoteDetails</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>

// Add script.js path here
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: App.js run's your application, so without including module name in app.js it will not initiate that Js file
And always use `ng-app` directive on `<htm ng-app="myApp">` so it will be available for whole page